# Symfony: Query Builder advanced joining

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I have 3 entities

```
[User] ---OneToMany---> [UserRole] ---ManyToOne---> [Role]
```

Hence there exists a join table `user_role`.

I want to create a `QueryBuilder`, that returns:

> All users, that have a specific role (role identified by any property).

I struggle with this, as I have to handle a join with a `many-to-many` relation. Easy in pure SQL, but I fail to facilitate the QueryBuilder for this.

Joining the `User` and the `Role` entities directly fails, I have to find a way to include the link table `user_role`.

Can someone hint me to manage this?

**Update**

This is an excerpt from what I have now:

```
->add('adm', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'ZanderUserBundle:User',
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $r) {
                $qb = $r->createQueryBuilder('u');
                $qb->join('ZanderUserBundle:Role', 'r')->where("r.role = 'ROLE_MANAGER'");

                return $qb;
            },
            'label' => 'Manager',
            'attr'  => array(
                'class' => 'inputElement'
        )))
```

Result is, that all users are returned.

Comment: Update your question adding what you've tried so far.

Comment: doctrine can join many2many relations, please show what you've tried with errors

Answer (score 0):

To get this result you could execute following inside your user repository:

```
$queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');
$queryBuilder->innerJoin('u.roles', 'r')
             ->where('r.role = :role')
             ->setParameter('role', 'ROLE_MANAGER');
$query = $queryBuilder->getQuery();
$users = $query->getResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

```
$qb = $r->createQueryBuilder('u');
$qb->innerJoin('u.roles', 'r', 'WITH', 'r.role = :role')
   ->setParameter('role', 'ROLE_MANAGER');
```